# Suppose X has a Binomial(n,p) distribution. Then what is its moment generating function

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

Suppose $X$ has a $Binomial(n,p)$ distribution. Then its moment generating function (MGF) $M_{X}(t)$ is $(pe^t+(1-p))^n$.

But what is the MGF of $-X$,  i.e. $M_{-X}(t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{-tX})$?

Is it $M_{-X}(t)$= $(pe^{-t}+(1-p))^n$?

Or should the notation be $M_{X}(-t)$ and let $X$ be positive?

Comment: $X$ cannot be negative if it has a Binomial distribution, so it would be the second. $X$ tells you the # of success in $p$ tries, and you can't have negative successes.

Comment: @measure_theory good observation, thanks! Then I guess it should be:  $M_{X}(-t)$= $(pe^{-t}+(1-p))^n$?

Comment: Yeah, $M_{X}(-t)  = (pe^{-t} + (1-p))^n$ is correct if $X \sim B(n,p)$